# Android application architecture - browsing an xml file

Tags: java, android, mobile

This is more of an overall architecture question about Android, and I'm curious what the community thinks is best practice for this type of endeavor. I am developing an Android application which loads an xml file which is stored on the device. My first question is, when you are dealing with a formatted xml file in the scope of an Android application, and the main point of the application is to sort of "browse" through the nodes of the xml, is it smarter to "load the xml" (not really sure what the term is) into memory and do it that way? Or is it smarter to take the xml, write it to an internal database (still getting used to the whole SQL Lite concept), and then browse through the data that way? The latter seems like a roundabout way, but I'm trying to understand core concepts here.

This brings me to my second question. If I were to draw out how the data from this XML "flows", the immediate answer in my head as far as what I know about Android is, a bunch of ListViews. Node 1 has 2 choices. This loads two choices into a ListView. When you click on the first node, it goes to the corresponding subnode in the xml, which has, say, four choices. I create a ListView with 4 choices. So on and so forth.

Does this make logical sense? Am I looking at the approach wrong? Is there a better way to do it using a different object that makes more sense? Any references to things that have already been done for me to compare to would be helpful as well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert the XML into a sqlite database. Just parse it in memory.

As far as your other questions, I'd have one activity that extends from `ListActivity`. Override `onListItemClick()` and make it start your activity again with some kind of pointer to the next element to browse.

Doing it this way will make the activity stack behave well as the user presses the back button.

Comment: This makes sense to me, and was what I thought... I just dont know enough about the OS yet to know if there is a better set of controls intended for this.

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on the specific use case you have and the size of XML file. For most parts, I think you will have  a heck of hard time placing your XML in the database unless you already have data model that is represented by XML and suitable for persistence. You surely don't want to do it with random XML.

If you have small XML you can always load it in memory using DOM. That will make it easy to navigate. But with large XML, you need to consider some streaming API (Stax) and read directly from file.

Comment: Interesting, I wasnt aware of Stax, but will look into it. So far, the xml files are relatively small, but its probably smart to plan for the largest common denominator. I'm going to do some searching on the matter, but have you seen any good tutorials or sample code for loading an xml into DOM and then browsing the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is relational database, so you need to store data from xml in DB only if you need to perform relational operation with data (e.g. selection/update/grouping so on). If you need just to go through DOM and do something (e.g. count specific nodes), I believe you should not parse xml to DB.